# Read data from SqlDataSource or GridView

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, dataview

I have SqlDataSource and GridView on web form. GridView.DataSourceID = mySqlDataSource.

When I call myGridView.DataBind(), all data successfully bind on the page.

How is it possible to read already got data from mySqlDataSource or myGridView objects as DataTable or DataView? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The data in the gridview can read by using FindControl property of Gridview control. For example,  for reading  values set in the Checkbox column in the grid.

```
    for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 

{

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("checkbox1");

            //here code for using value captured in chk 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your data set isn't gigantic, you could store it in the `Session`, bind your `GridView` to the `Session` data, and then re-use the `Session` data in your other web objects.

Your code would then look something like this (you'll have to forgive any minor inaccuracies -- I'm away from my development box at the moment):

```
protected override OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit();

    if (Page.IsPostback == false)
    {
        SetSessionData();
    }
    //
    // Set your GridView, DataTable, DataView, etc. events here.
    //
}

void SetSessionData();
{
        List<YourDataBoundObject> myDataBoundObject = GetYourDataBoundObject(); // Or Collection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, etc.
        Session["data"] = myDataBoundObject;
}

void YourGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindYourGridView();
}

void BindYourGridView()
{
    YourGridView.DataSource = GetSessionData();
    YourGridView.DataBind();
}

List<YourDataBoundObject> GetSessionData()
{
    return (List<YourDataBoundObject>) Session["data"];
}

void YourDataTable_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindYourDataTable();
}

void BindYourDataTable()
{
    YourDataTable.DataSource = GetSessionData();
    YourDataTable.DataBind();
}
```